# android : cursor ignores first row in table

Tags: java, android

i have a database and i want to use a cursor to collect all objects of  one column in a string[]... so here is my code:

```
c.moveToFirst();
int i = 0;
String[] addresses = new String[c.getCount()];
while(c.moveToNext()) {
    addresses[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
    i++;
}
c.close();
```

but when I used this code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String in : addresses) {
    builder.append("" + in + " ");
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

for showing all objects in my string[], I got this:

`234567null`.. but right answer should be like this : `1234567` ..!

so where is my mistake?? ... thanks!!

Comment: You use moveToFirst for accessing first record but after you are invoking moveToNext before reading first address. You should eventually use a do while loop here.

Comment: oh! yes!... plz tell me how in one answer...thanks...

Comment: Like this: `//c.moveToFirst();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*tl;dr* Remove the call to `moveToFirst()` and it will work.

A new `Cursor` starts out at position `-1` and by calling `moveToFirst` it will move to position `0`.

If you use `while(moveToNext)` *after* calling `moveToFirst` the first index accessed in the loop will be `1`, skipping `0`.

Cursor loops are best done just using

```
cursor.moveToPosition(-1); // in case you accessed it before
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // ...
}
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option for using cursor:

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // read your cursor params
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the:

```
c..moveToFirst();
```

The cursor starts from before the first result, and *moveToNext* will take it to the first row.

The way you have written it, the cursor skips the first row as *moveToFirst* takes it to 1st row and then *moveToNext* takes it to the 2nd. Thus the *addresses* has one string less in the end and it gives null as u have fixed the length of the array. You would have got *234567* if you would have used a list which would have made it clear that it skips the first.